# Автозаполнение поля HTML, JSP

Tags: html, jsp

Возникла проблема. Используя теги от Spring

```
<form:label path="id">
    <spring:message text="ID"/>
</form:label>

<form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8" disabled="true"/>
<form:hidden path="id"/>
```

Форма заполнялась автоматически значением вытащенным из БД. Решил использовать формы HTML и наткнулся на проблему.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Имя</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" id="name" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

Теперь поля при обновлении объекта не заполняются автоматически, что заставляет вводить все заново. Это в принципе и очевидно.

Есть ли возможность реализовать подобный функционал из-под html?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"
       placeholder="Имя" class="form-control" value="${obj.property}" />
```

Comment: Благодарю, помогло.)

Comment: @АртёмБондарев [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)